# Spark2.4 Unable to overwrite table from same table

Tags: scala, apache-spark-sql, spark2.4.4

I am trying to insert data into a table using insert overwrite statement but I am getting below error.

```
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Cannot overwrite a path that is also being read from.;
```

command is as below

```
spark.sql("INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE edm_hive SELECT run_number+1 from edm_hive")
```

I am trying to use temp table, store the results and then update in final table but that is also not working.

Also I am trying to insert record into table using some variable but that is also not working.
e.g.

```
spark.sql("INSERT into TABLE Feed_metadata_s2 values ('LOGS','StartTimestamp',$StartTimestamp)")
```

Please suggest

Answer (score 0):

This solution works well for me. I added that property in sparkSession.

[Spark HiveContext : Insert Overwrite the same table it is read from](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46143084/spark-hivecontext-insert-overwrite-the-same-table-it-is-read-from)

```
val spark = SparkSession.builder()
      .config("spark.sql.hive.convertMetastoreParquet","false")
```